# How to combine stack, padding and listview to achieve this?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

What I am trying to achieve is to stack elements on top that contains padding from top and listview with background, like here:

[image: before scroll]

[image: after scroll]

And my code now looks like this:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Padding(
     child: Material(
      child: Listview.builder()
    ),
  ]
),
```

After building web, I checked and scrolling lags a little (you may check with mobile only - here: [project website](https://koza-nostra-b2b.web.app))

Maybe there is a better approach for this?

Comment: Use a persistent bottom sheet to achieve this, you can use this package too https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_bottom_sheet

Comment: Tried it, but is seems to not be scrollable with touch for some reason

Comment: Please update your code with same, So I can check it out